# Dynamically generate rich menuitems inside rich context menu

Tags: jsf-2, foreach, richfaces, jstl, uirepeat

I am trying to dynamically generate rich menu items inside a rich context menu component. Here is my code:

```
<ui:repeat var="group" value="#{myBean.groups}" >
  <div align="center"> 
    <rich:panel>
      <h:graphicImage value="#{group.iconUrl}"/>
      <rich:contextMenu attached="true">
        <c:forEach var="child" items="#{group.children}">
          <rich:menuItem label="#{child.name}" />
        </c:forEach>
      </rich:contextMenu>
    </rich:panel>   
  </div>
</ui:repeat>
```

I am using this tag library :

```
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core
```

My problem is that the menu items aren't being generated. I have also tried replacing **c:forEach** with **ui:repeat** but it still won't work.

I tried a little experimentation to eliminate some factors. I removed rich context menu and used ui:repeat

```
<ui:repeat var="group" value="#{myBean.groups}" >
  <div align="center"> 
    <rich:panel>
      <h:graphicImage value="#{group.iconUrl}"/>
      <ui:repeat var="child" value="#{group.children}">
         <h:outputText value="#{child.name}" />
      </ui:repeat>
    </rich:panel>   
  </div>
</ui:repeat>
```

This code snippet above **worked**. I guess there is a conflict with the rendering of the context menu and the ui repeat.

Sadly, I really kind of need to place group.children in a rich context menu component. Can you suggest any approach that will help me achieve what I want?

**NOTE: I am using servlet version 3.0**

Answer (score 1):

The `<c:forEach>` runs during view build time, when the XHTML file is to be transformed into a JSF component tree. The `<ui:repeat>` runs during view render time, when the JSF component tree is about to produce HTML.

So, in your particular example, at the moment the `<c:forEach>` runs, the `#{group}` variable as definied by `<ui:repeat>` is nowhere available in the EL scope and the `<c:forEach>` basically retrieves `null` as items value and hence has nothing to iterate over.

Your construct will only work if you replace the outer `<ui:repeat>` by `<c:forEach>` as well.

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense/3343681#3343681)